# Partial Red Mark on top left corner of iphone 13 pro Max

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I am experiencing a problem with my iPhone 13 Pro Max. A red mark is visible on the top left corner of the display; usually when I switch between apps. This is my second phone that is showing this red mark. Has anyone had this type of problem before, please?

[image: Photo of partial red circle in the upper left corner of the iPhone screen]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  It's extremely difficult to help you figure this out with the description you provided.  We're not there looking over your shoulder when this happens so it would help to post a screenshot, provide more details, as well as what you've already done to resolve the problem yourself.

Comment: Thank you for you answer and I have just added a picture of it right now

Comment: Yea, that's strange that you had it on 2 iPhones.  It looks like a hardware problem, especially if it sticks around when different apps are running.  Have you tried to wipe your device and set it up as a new device (not restore from a backup)?

Comment: Yes I did erased everything as a new phone two times aswell, I tought it’s something from software because it happened to me on two different iphones

Comment: If it doesn't come back after a wipe and restore you may need to go through the process (annoying as it may be...) of adding apps one or two at a time until the issue pops up and points to those one or two apps.